# The constructor WebDriverWait(chromeDriver, int) is undefined

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver

WebDriverWait is not recognized even though it is imported in the eclipse IDE.

[image]

Does anyone know the possible reason and fix for this?

Comment: Update the question with the code.

Comment: i added links to the images

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are trying to use

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
```

which will call this constructor

```
  /**
   * Wait will ignore instances of NotFoundException that are encountered (thrown) by default in
   * the 'until' condition, and immediately propagate all others.  You can add more to the ignore
   * list by calling ignoring(exceptions to add).
   *
   * @param driver The WebDriver instance to pass to the expected conditions
   * @param timeoutInSeconds The timeout in seconds when an expectation is called
   * @see WebDriverWait#ignoring(java.lang.Class)
   * @deprecated Instead, use {@link WebDriverWait#WebDriverWait(WebDriver, Duration)}.
   */
  @Deprecated
  public WebDriverWait(WebDriver driver, long timeoutInSeconds) {
    this(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(timeoutInSeconds));
  }
```

As you can see, it has been **deprecated** in newer version of **Selenium** **i.e Selenium 4**

**Solution:**

You should rather use this constructor:

```
  public WebDriverWait(WebDriver driver, Duration timeout) {
    this(
        driver,
        timeout,
        Duration.ofMillis(DEFAULT_SLEEP_TIMEOUT),
        Clock.systemDefaultZone(),
        Sleeper.SYSTEM_SLEEPER);
  }
```

**Your effective code:**

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(30));
```

should get the job done for you.

Answer (score 2):

```
WebDriverWait w=new WebDriverWait(driver,10)
```

basically, this is deprecated.

This issue can be suppressed by changing the  above statement in the following ways

```
WebDriverWait webdwait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10));

WebDriverWait webdwait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofHours(10));
```

Answer (score 0):

WebDriverWait is missing from your project.
1.Check you have used the import the statement  org.openqa.selenium.support.ui
2. Either add the jar manually to the project (or) if it is Maven based project use mvn clean install , and reopen the IDE- you should be good.

Comment: says "Only a type can be imported. org.openqa.selenium.support.ui resolves to a package"