# Webdriverwait in selenium java

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait, selenium-java

```
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    WebDriverWait w =new WebDriverWait(driver,5);
```

I am getting an error for the second line. the error is "The constructor `WebDriverWait(WebDriver,int)` is undefined"

Can someone please help me out here?

I tried to initialize the webdriver wait class. I foollowed the syntax as instructed but I am getting an error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The constructor WebDriverWait(chromeDriver, int) is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71761074/the-constructor-webdriverwaitchromedriver-int-is-undefined)

Answer (score 1):

You must be using latest Selenium 4.xx , you should do it like this

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(30));
```

The constructor which accepted wait time in long has been depreciated in version 4 and is removed in the latest releases

```
   @Deprecated
  public WebDriverWait(WebDriver driver, long timeoutInSeconds) {
    this(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(timeoutInSeconds));
  }
```