# After updating the selenium version getting

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

After updating the selenium version ,getting error `The constructor WebDriverWait(WebDriver, int) is undefined`. Please I need a solution for this.

I tried this solution but facing issue

```
public WebDriverWait(WebDriver driver, Duration timeout) {
    this(
        driver,
        timeout,
        Duration.ofMillis(DEFAULT_SLEEP_TIMEOUT),
        Clock.systemDefaultZone(),
        Sleeper.SYSTEM_SLEEPER);
  }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The constructor WebDriverWait(chromeDriver, int) is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71761074/the-constructor-webdriverwaitchromedriver-int-is-undefined)

Comment: Don't recreate the webdriverwait class, just know that they changed it's constructor so that it takes a time unit instead of "int".  So change your call to using a Duration instead of an int.

Comment: Thank you, i tried ur solution and it's working fine